# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader makes Android program crash when switching activity

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm trying to build a program that lets me connect to a health device via bluetooth, but when I try to run it on the emulator or a phone, it crashes when I try to access the Activity. This is the code for the activity that doesn't fully run:

```
package com.example.baard.mysqldemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;



import android.Manifest;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.empatica.empalink.EmpaDeviceManager;
import com.empatica.empalink.ConnectionNotAllowedException;

import com.empatica.empalink.config.EmpaSensorStatus;
import com.empatica.empalink.config.EmpaSensorType;
import com.empatica.empalink.config.EmpaStatus;
import com.empatica.empalink.delegate.EmpaDataDelegate;
import com.empatica.empalink.delegate.EmpaStatusDelegate;

import static com.empatica.empalink.config.EmpaStatus.*;

/**
 * Created by arnar on 01.11.2017.
 */

public class Bconnect extends AppCompatActivity implements EmpaDataDelegate, EmpaStatusDelegate{

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION=2;
    private static final long STREAMING_TIME = 3600000; // Stops streaming 3600 seconds(1 hour) after connection
    private static final long SCANNING_TIME = 10000;//Stop scanning after 10 sec

    private static final String EMPATICA_API_KEY = "234acf07689e4d2aacfe46bf5b6a816c";

    private EmpaDeviceManager deviceManager;
    private EmpaStatus status;

    private TextView accel_xLabel;
    private TextView accel_yLabel;
    private TextView accel_zLabel;
    private TextView bvpLabel;
    private TextView edaLabel;
    private TextView ibiLabel;
    private TextView hrLabel;
    private TextView temperatureLabel;
    private TextView batteryLabel;
    private TextView statusLabel;
    private Button searchDeviceBtn;
    private TextView deviceNameLabel;
    private RelativeLayout dataCnt;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.i("*******","BT connect starter");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bconnect);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


       //Lager en ny EmpaDeviceManager
        Log.i("*********","Kjører til devicemng");
        deviceManager = new EmpaDeviceManager(getApplicationContext(), this, this);
        Log.i("*********","works");
        //Initialiserer devicemanager med vår API-key
        deviceManager.authenticateWithAPIKey(EMPATICA_API_KEY);
        requestPermissions(new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        }, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //deviceManager.StopScanning
    }

    @Override
    protected void  onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        deviceManager.cleanUp();
    }

    //--------------------------ANDROID-TJENESTER

    @Override
    public void didRequestEnableBluetooth() {
        // Ber brukeren skru på Bluetooth
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    //------------------------Empatica Status Delegate

    @Override
    public void didDiscoverDevice(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice, String deviceName, int rssi, boolean allowed){

        Toast.makeText(this, "Fant en enhet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(allowed){
            deviceManager.stopScanning();
            try{
                deviceManager.connectDevice(bluetoothDevice);
                updateLabel(deviceNameLabel, "To: " + deviceName);

            } catch (ConnectionNotAllowedException e){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Beklager, du kan ikke koble til denne enheten", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void didUpdateSensorStatus(EmpaSensorStatus status, EmpaSensorType type) {
        // Ikke implementert ennå
    }

    @Override
    public void didUpdateStatus(EmpaStatus status){
        this.status = status;
        //Oppdaterer UI
        updateLabel(statusLabel, status.name());
        //Enheten er klar for bruk

        if(status == EmpaStatus.READY){
            searchDeviceBtn.setEnabled(true);
            updateLabel(statusLabel, status.name()+"- Skru på enheten din, deretter trykk på SCAN");
        }
        else if(status == EmpaStatus.CONNECTED){
            //Stopper streamingen etter STREAMING_TIME er ferdig
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dataCnt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //Kobler fra enheten
                            deviceManager.disconnect();
                        }
                    }, STREAMING_TIME);
                }
            });
            //Device Manager koblet fra en enhet

        } else if (status==EmpaStatus.DISCONNECTED){
            updateLabel(deviceNameLabel, "");
        }
    }


    //------------------------Empatica Data Delegate

    @Override
    public void didReceiveAcceleration(int x, int y, int z, double timestamp) {
        updateLabel(accel_xLabel, "" + x);
        updateLabel(accel_yLabel, "" + y);
        updateLabel(accel_zLabel, "" + z);
    }

    @Override
    public void didReceiveBatteryLevel(float battery, double timestamp) {
        updateLabel(batteryLabel, String.format("%.0f %%", battery * 100));
    }

    @Override
    public void didReceiveGSR(float gsr, double timestamp) {
        updateLabel(edaLabel, "" + gsr);
    }

    @Override
    public void didReceiveIBI(float ibi, double timestamp) {
        updateLabel(ibiLabel, "" + ibi);
        float hr=60/ibi;
        updateLabel(hrLabel,""+ Math.round(hr));
    }

    @Override
    public void didReceiveTemperature(float temp, double timestamp) {
        updateLabel(temperatureLabel, "" + temp);
    }

    @Override
    public void didReceiveBVP(float bvp, double timestamp) {
        updateLabel(bvpLabel, "" + bvp);
    }

    //Click Event
    public void scan(View v){
        searchDeviceBtn.setEnabled(false);
        deviceManager.startScanning();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(status==EmpaStatus.CONNECTED||status==EmpaStatus.CONNECTING) return;
                        deviceManager.stopScanning();
                        Toast.makeText(Bconnect.this, "Fant ikke noen enheter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        searchDeviceBtn.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                },SCANNING_TIME);
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateLabel(final TextView label, final String text) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                label.setText(text);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Beneath is the information provided by the logcat:

```
11-01 16:55:23.185 19051-19051/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-01 16:55:23.188 19051-19051/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
11-01 16:55:23.300 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.baard.mysqldemo-1/lib/x86
11-01 16:55:23.334 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-01 16:55:23.467 19051-19066/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-01 16:55:23.467 19051-19066/com.example.baard.mysqldemo D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
11-01 16:55:23.468 19051-19066/com.example.baard.mysqldemo W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
11-01 16:55:23.468 19051-19066/com.example.baard.mysqldemo D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
11-01 16:55:23.491 19051-19066/com.example.baard.mysqldemo D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa9b050c0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
11-01 16:55:23.514 19051-19066/com.example.baard.mysqldemo D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9b050c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9b032b0)
11-01 16:55:23.543 19051-19066/com.example.baard.mysqldemo D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa9b050c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa9b032b0)
11-01 16:55:25.994 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/*******: Open BT trykke
11-01 16:55:26.018 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/*******: BT connect starter
11-01 16:55:26.047 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/*********: Kjører til devicemng
11-01 16:55:26.085 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.empatica.empalink.EmpaDeviceManager$4>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Callback;
11-01 16:55:26.085 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void com.example.baard.mysqldemo.Bconnect.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Bconnect.java:101)
11-01 16:55:26.085 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
11-01 16:55:26.085 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
11-01 16:55:26.085 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
11-01 16:55:26.085 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
11-01 16:55:26.085 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.squareup.okhttp.Callback" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.baard.mysqldemo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.baard.mysqldemo-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void com.example.baard.mysqldemo.Bconnect.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Bconnect.java:101)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
11-01 16:55:26.086 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
11-01 16:55:26.105 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.empatica.empalink.EmpaDeviceManager$5>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Callback;
11-01 16:55:26.105 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void com.example.baard.mysqldemo.Bconnect.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Bconnect.java:101)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.squareup.okhttp.Callback" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.baard.mysqldemo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.baard.mysqldemo-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void com.example.baard.mysqldemo.Bconnect.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Bconnect.java:101)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6662)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2599)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2707)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1460)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6077)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:866)
11-01 16:55:26.106 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:756)
11-01 16:55:26.114 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-01 16:55:26.115 19051-19051/com.example.baard.mysqldemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.baard.mysqldemo, PID: 19051
                                                                             java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.baard.mysqldemo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.baard.mysqldemo-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libempac.so"
                                                                                 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:972)
                                                                                 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)
                                                                                 at com.empatica.empalink.EmpaDeviceManager.<clinit>(EmpaDeviceManager.java:69)
                                                                                 at com.example.baard.mysqldemo.Bconnect.onCreate(Bconnect.java:101)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

I'd love some help here, as I really have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Try using the dependency instead of the .jar - `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0`

Comment: I tried it, and the first error is gone. However, I now get :java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.baard.mysqldemo-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.baard.mysqldemo-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884769/unsatisfiedlinkerror-dalvik-system-pathclassloader)

Comment: let me get it straight: I change the dependencies in the app build.gradle by adding compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'?